# Yahoo finance continuous futures historical data

Tags: futures, market-data, yahoofinance, yahoo

How is Yahoo Finance's continuous futures historical data calculated? Are these front-month numbers?

Comment: If you could provide a link that would help.

Comment: I'm asking the same question. One example is symbol CL-F, the crude oil. Is it a backadjusted front month historical series?
https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/CL=F?p=CL=F&.tsrc=fin-srch

Comment: If you click on the link from andrewf, choose 'chart' and select 'max' for date range, the result suggests no back-adjustment (otherwise the peak in '08 would have been much higher).

Comment: Is there an API that has continuous prices?